# How to sort the elements is lightning-dual-listbox based on the label?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-dom

I am trying to sort the elements in the dual list box, unfortunately i did not find any correct way to do it.

[image]

### This is my html component

```
<template>
    <lightning-dual-listbox name="languages"
                            label="Select Languages"
                            source-label="Available"
                            selected-label="Selected"
                            field-level-help="Select your preferred languages"
                            options={options}
                            onchange={handleChange}></lightning-dual-listbox>
    <div class="slds-box" >
        <p>Selected values are: {selected}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

and this is my javascript

---

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class DualListboxSimple extends LightningElement {
    _selected = [];

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
            { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
            { label: 'Spanish', value: 'es' },
            { label: 'French', value: 'fr' },
            { label: 'Italian', value: 'it' },
            { label: 'Japanese', value: 'ja' },
        ];
    }

    get selected() {
        return this._selected.length ? this._selected : 'none';
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this._selected = e.detail.value.sort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would suggest you to, edit your question with some code and what you have tried so far? Where does the list comes from, if from SOQL via apex, you can use order by. Otherwise you can use [JavaScript sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) at clientside.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW**

It looks like the component returns an array of VALUES only. Plus, it has it's own order, that a user can change - so you can't really modify the order on the right column, except by changing the options array.

So we need to sort the `values` elements of the `options` objects.

We only need to do this once, when the array is first initialized.

Try this:

```
sorted = false;
options_ = [
    { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
    { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
    { label: 'Spanish', value: 'es' },
    { label: 'French', value: 'fr' },
    { label: 'Italian', value: 'it' },
    { label: 'Japanese', value: 'ja' }
];
get options() {
  if (!this.sorted){
    this.options_ = this.options_.sort(this.sortLabels);
    this.sorted = true;
  }
  return this.options_;
}

sortLabels = (a,b)=>{
    const labelA = a.label.toUpperCase(); 
    const labelB = b.label.toUpperCase(); 
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OLD BELOW**

You need to sort on elements that are within objects of the array. The built in `Array.prototype.sort()` function is built to handle simple arrays like so:

```
["Apple","Orange","Banana"]
```

But you have a more complex structure and since the Array cannot easily infer what's in the objects that you have supplied in your array, you need to provide the sort function yourself.

Like this:

```
handleChange(e){
  let temp = e.detail.value;
  if (!temp || temp.length < 2){
    temp = [];
  }
  else {
    temp.sort((a, b) => {
      const labelA = a.label.toUpperCase(); 
      const labelB = b.label.toUpperCase(); 
      if (labelA < labelB) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (labelA > labelB) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }
  this._selected = temp;
}
```

Comment: I tired to use the above code, 
I got this following error, 
engine.js:6591 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label')

Comment: @Caspar Harmer This should work in theory but does not work. I guess it has something to do with how things are internally handled by the lightning-dual-listbox component.

Comment: Updated - realised that my first answer was not going to work.

Comment: Oh and the changehandler can be just `this._selected = e.detail.value;`